# strtok not splitting spaces correctly even with correct delimiter

Tags: arrays, c, command-line-arguments, strtok

I am attempting to split two words (and more) and put them into an array by splitting it into tokens with strtok. My delimitors include `" \t\n";` as shown below in the code. For example if I were to type in `"cat program.c"`, it just prints the `cat` token and not the `program.c` token and I have no idea why. Are my delimitors not correct or am I not splitting the string correctly? Here is the code

```
  char b[256];
  int k = 0;
  char *args[4];
  char *tokens;
  char delimiters[] = " \t\n";
  printf("Please enter the command you want to use:\n");
  scanf("%255s", b);
  tokens = strtok(b, delimiters);
  while (tokens != NULL){
    args[k++] = tokens;
    printf("%s\n",tokens);
    tokens = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
  }
```

Comment: `scanf("%255s", b);` Ouch. You care about providing a length limit for your input but then you use a value that is way off for your buffer: `char b[100];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not `strtok()`, but rather `scanf()`.  An `%s` field directive scans a *whitespace-delimited* string, so when the input is `cat program.c`, only the "cat" ever makes it into array `b` in the first place. (The  `program.c` remains waiting to be read.)  If you want to read a whole line of input at a time, then I would recommend `fgets()`, instead.

Comment: Something like `scanf("%[^\n]100s", b)` would work, but I agree that `fgets()` is a better choice. `scanf()` is a minefield of problems.